# Configure Log4j in Camel context

Tags: log4j, apache-camel

Is it possible to configure a Camel route to send a message to a specific log4j logger? For example, I have the following logger:

```
<logger name="com.me.log.mylogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="file_appender_messages" />
</logger>
```

`file_appender_messages` is just a `RollingFileAppender`.

I then try to log it using the following in my Camel context:

```
<to uri="log:com.me.log.mylogger?level=INFO" />
```

But it outputs on the command line instead of the log file specified in `file_appender_messages`:

```
25-Oct-2012 11:46:44 org.apache.camel.processor.CamelLogger log
INFO: [MESSAGE BODY]
```

I would like to be able to use dffferent loggers for messages from different sources. I could do it in my message processors but ideally it could be configured in the route xml. Can it be done?

Comment: Which version of Camel are you using ?

Comment: 2.7.2 - I know it's a little older, but it's a work thing.

Comment: I should work. Are you sure your log4j configuration is loaded?

Comment: Yeah, getting the Logger in Java using `Logger.getLogger("com.me.log.myLogger")` and calling `.info` on it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by defining the Logger as a Bean in my application XML file

```
<bean id="myLogger" class="org.apache.log4j.Logger" factory-method="getLogger">
    <constructor-arg value="com.me.log.mylogger"/>
</bean>
```

Then in my route, when I want to log the message I just direct it to the relevant method on the Bean

```
<to uri="bean:myLogger?method=info" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Camel uses slf4j since some time. So you have to first configure slf4j to use log4j as backend. In maven add the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```