# How to log Apache camel logs to separate log file

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using log4j in my application which has Apache camel and here I need to log the messages sent through camel to separate log file other than log4j application log file.

Comment: And? Did configuring a new file logger not work?

Comment: i want to use .to("log: component in camel to log to differnt file but this only logs in console . so what should i be doing to add to differnt log file

Comment: Can you elaborate your question little bit to get exact answer?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066962/configure-log4j-in-camel-context) is likely to help you get ahead.

Comment: how to enable camel logs component to log to a seperate file other than console?  from example from reading content from ftp file and copying into another location . So i need to log some specific  data between to and from to seperate log file

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Log component's](http://camel.apache.org/log.html) documentation?

Comment: Hope this will help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922822/logging-simple-text-in-apache-camel-logs

Comment: All above solutions log to console but thats not my need:(

Comment: Camel uses slf4j for logging. You can hook in `log4j` as a logging instance to slf4j. If you are already seeing output on console, you are probably using a `ConsoleAppender`, you need to change your log4j configuration to throw the logs into a file. Something like `RollingFileAppender` can do it. I have no clear idea at what stage you are stuck at.